# Does it support 3D pie chart?

Tags: 3d, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using Highcharts on my web, and I have the need for a 3D pie chart.

Does Highcharts support 3D pie charts? If so can someone show an example?

Answer (score 4):

It's the top most requested feature

```
http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general
```

and it looks like is is coming this year. Meanwhile, you can add radial gradients. http://jsfiddle.net/LCdVd/243/

--- Update ---
3D pie charts are now supported:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie